# Python 3 decode("utf-8") is adding newlines where there should only be spaces. I do I stop this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, decode, password-hash

I am trying to read in some data from the output of a different program. I know I can open files and read them in however for the purpose of this question I have created the example file testdata.txt which looks as follows:

```
cat testdata.txt 
my.local\Sho Admin:13951:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:::
my.local\Sho Help:13952:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:::
my.local\Sho Production:13953:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:::
my.local\Sho Test:13954:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:::
```

In my code I am trying to use subprocess.check_output to make a system call and read the output into variables. However when I do it without the decode("utf-8") its in the form of bytes. So in an effort to convert it to strings I used the decode("utf-8) however then it adds new lines where there are spaces.

```
output = subprocess.check_output(('cat', 'testdata.txt'), shell=False).decode('utf-8')
pprint.pprint((output))
```

When I excute this code I get these new lines.

```
('my.local\\Sho '
 'Admin:13951:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:::\n'
 'my.local\\Sho '
 'Help:13952:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:::\n'
 'my.local\\Sho '
 'Production:13953:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:::\n'
 'my.local\\Sho '
 'Test:13954:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:::\n')
```

I am trying to make the code look like this:

```
('my.local\\Sho Admin:13951:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:::\n'
 'my.local\\Sho Help:13952:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:::\n'
 'my.local\\Sho Production:13953:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:::\n'
 'my.local\\Sho Test:13954:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:::\n')
```

Comment: If you are just reading the file why not do it with `open`?

Comment: Just a wild guess... this isn't `decode`, thats `pprint` wrapping the lines. Yep, reproduced, posting an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats 'pprint' doing it. Take a look at this little test code. And yea, you can tell pprint where to wrap, for example, `pprint(test, width=300)`.

**Code:**

```
from pprint import pprint
test=r"""my.local\Sho Admin:13951:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:::
my.local\Sho Help:13952:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:::
my.local\Sho Production:13953:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:::
my.local\Sho Test:13954:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:::"""
print(test)
pprint(test)
```

**Output:**

```
my.local\Sho Admin:13951:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:::
my.local\Sho Help:13952:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:::
my.local\Sho Production:13953:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:::
my.local\Sho Test:13954:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:::
('my.local\\Sho '
 'Admin:13951:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:::\n'
 'my.local\\Sho '
 'Help:13952:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:::\n'
 'my.local\\Sho '
 'Production:13953:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:::\n'
 'my.local\\Sho '
 'Test:13954:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:::')
```

Comment: !!! Thanks I have been looking at this code for too long. I appreciate it. smh. ha.

Comment: @sho_luv, sometimes a fresh pair of eyes is all what it takes to spot something like that, lol

Comment: The trick is to notice that there aren't commas between the string literals, so they just get concatenated together; and there aren't `\n` at the end of the short strings.